# Iterate over Mongodb cursor from aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is code from my node.js backend:

```
app.get('/getpossibleconnections', auth, function(req, res){
    if (req.authenticated == false){
        res.send("Your session has expired.");
    } else {
        User.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: { $nin: req.decoded.username.connections } } },
            { $sample: { size: 10 } },
        ]).next(function(err, docs) {
            console.log("horray");
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried replacing `next()` with `toArray()` and `each()` as suggested here:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/aggregation/

However, I receive the same error every time:

`TypeError: User.aggregate(...).next is not a function`

Why can't I iterate over the returned documents with any sort of function?

Is it because `User` isn't a collection?

Comment: one possible solution would be to simply pass a callback and to iterate on the result

Comment: what is the variable "User" being assigned to? in the link provided, they connected to a database and then set a variable to a collection in that database, are you doing the same?

Comment: @devonJS User is a model, but I'm using mongoose and from what I understand mongoose automatically associates a collection with each model type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cursor = User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: { $nin: req.decoded.username.connections } } },
    { $sample: { size: 10 } },
]).cursor().exec();

cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    //do something with doc
});
```

Mongoose handles an aggregate to cursor object differently than Mongodb-native as you posted in your link.  More information here: [mongoose aggregate cursor documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor)